# How do you create custom settings for a vs code extension?

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have been researching for hours but to no avail.
Pretty much all VsCode extensions will have custom made settings, and they show up in the default settings json file like this from the Red Hat Java extension:

`"java.dependency.showOutline": true,`

I'm trying to write my own extension and I have found a lot of useful stuff, I can create custom themes, snippets, commands, etc. and it's all well documented on the VsCode API site, but I need to create custom user-defined settings, and I cannot find ANYWHERE that explains how to do so. Does anyone know?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration

Answer (score 1):

This is done using [contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points), JSON declarations in the `contributes` field of your extension's `package.json` file.

You want the [configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration) contribution point.

For example:

```json
// package.json

{
  "contributes": {
    "configuration": {
      "title": "",
      "properties": {
        "scope.name": {
          "type": "",
          "default": "",
          "description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can read those values using

```js
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('your-extension-name')
```